# Is there any means to detect adding/removing of descendants in the visual tree

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-tree

I have a pair of controls, let's call them `BigDaddy` and `Flea`. One or more `Flea` elements may appear anywhere in the visual tree of `BigDaddy`. Is there any way to detect the adding/removing of `Flea` objects on `BigDaddy` given that there is no requirement that it be an immediate child?

Example trees:

```
<my:BigDaddy>
    <my:Flea /> <!-- Flea is an immediate child -->
</my:BigDaddy>
```

-- OR --

```
<my:BigDaddy>
    <SomethingElse>
        <Canvas>
            <my:Flea />
            <!-- Flea is not an immediate child but still needs to be detected -->
        </Canvas>
    </SomethingElse>
</my:BigDaddy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could try something with reflection and property tracking, like when BigDaddy loads you can check the visual tree for a Flea element using reflection and then add a property changed listener to it's parent to track the Children nodes.